# LXLE's system monitor on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Tags: software-recommendation

I would like to use the same application to manage my system resources as LXLE distro uses by default. I searched a lit bit on the web, but I couldn't find which is that app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LXLE uses the LXDE desktop environment. LXTask is the default system monitor, so that could be what you're looking for - I can't know for sure since you haven't given any clue as to what it looks like.

You can find `.deb` download links for LXTask [here](http://people.linux.org.tw/~andrew/debian/lxde/lxtask/)

In case you're wondering, LXTask look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Run, in a terminal, `sudo apt-get install lxtask` to install LXTask, LXDE's task manager.

(!!!) After installing, you're going to get a duplicate task manager entry in the Dash. You can run it from a terminal, with the `lxtask` command.

Comment: Good point about the duplicate entry. One can sudo edit the .desktop file of the other task manager (in /usr/share/applications) to add the line "NoDisplay=true" to prevent the Dash from showing it. See http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html for details.